# Back slash in my Django url

Tags: python, django, url

My django url works only when I use a slash after my url. Of the following two, only the second works. The first one does not work:

1). http://10.165.19.167:8000/downloady9cHTML/Intro.html/

2). http://10.165.19.167:8000/downloady9cHTML/Intro.html

What can I do if I want my second url to work? i.e. I dont want to put a back slash at the end of my url?

Thanks..

Comment: please share the convenient piece from `urls.py` file

Comment: urls.py:    

url(r'^downloady9cHTML/(?P<file_name>.*)/$', app.views.download_y9cfile1),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to require a slash, don't put one in the URL pattern.

```
url(r'^downloady9cHTML/(?P<file_name>.*)$', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Django's **[APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#append-slash)**

> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.

### Alternative

edit

`url(r'^downloady9cHTML/(?P<file_name>.*)/$', app.views.download_y9cfile1)`

to

`url(r'^downloady9cHTML/(?P<file_name>.*)', app.views.download_y9cfile1)`

The `/$` at the end is removed. The reason being regex `$` states end of the regex pattern. That means you are explicitly telling it to match with `\`. If you remove only the `\` then it will work for the second url (in your question)only. If you remove `\$` it will work for both the urls.

Comment: Can the down voter kindly explain what is wrong? Will correct it in my post.